# plonetruegallery: Download link or button, so users can download a viewed image?

Tags: gallery, plone, image-gallery

I use [collective.plonetruegallery](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.plonetruegallery) for image galleries within Plone and I like it. However, what I miss is a "download" button or a simple "link" in order to let users actually download a image. The "Galleria" display view of plonetruegallery does seem to offer such a link/button -- does any of the other display views? Or any other solution whithout having to hack the plonetruegallery addon myself?

I know that you can right click and then choose "download image" among several other options within your preferred browser -- however, for a dumb user to cumbersome ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have added an option to collective.ptg.contactsheet (1.1.2) that let you choose between going to the content or downloading it.
Espen

Answer (score 1):

There's not a built-in "feature" to do this.  You can see which of the gallery views might have this; looks like you've already found one.  I'm sure you could easily customize another one to include such a link, simply by following the example in Galleria.

Answer (score 1):

This is quite easy to make. The url to download the image would probably be:
/path/to/image/download

One option could be to just add an action.
If you want to have this for a specific gallery, I can probably fix it.
(go to https://github.com/collective/collective.ptg.contactsheet or whatever gallerytype you want it for  and add an "Issue"

Espen